# Specific starting values not filling out array

Tags: javascript, html

In my program, I have a form that takes two numbers the user inputs and then creates an array of every number between the two. This works fine for most values, but certain combinations of numbers will fail to fill the array with any numbers at all. The relevant code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<form id="input">
    <label for="min">Minimum number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="min" name="min" class="field"><br><br>
    <label for="max">Maximum number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="max" name="max" class="field"><br><br>
</form>
```

JS:

```
let min = document.getElementById("min").value;
let max = document.getElementById("max").value;
let range = [];
while(min <= max) {
        range.push(min++);
    };
```

This works perfectly fine for a lot of ranges like 1-10, 1-100, or 10-20, but fails if a range like 3-10 or 5-10 is input. Through my troubleshooting so far, I've concluded that it's not any one min or max value that breaks, but instead just certain arbitrary combinations of numbers. It's also 100% consistent and reproduceable, if that means anything.

Any help or insight into what I've done wrong would be appreciated :)

Comment: When are you calling this js function? On form submit or on page load?

Comment: The function is called on form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you get values from your inputs they are strings.  Use parseInt()

```
let min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
let max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
```

```js
function myFunction(event){
event.preventDefault();
let min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
let max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
let range = [];
while(min <= max) {
        range.push(min++);
    };
    
  console.log(range)
    
    }
```

```html
    <label for="min">Minimum number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="min" name="min" class="field"><br><br>
    <label for="max">Maximum number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="max" name="max" class="field"><br><br>
    <button onclick='myFunction(event)'>push</button>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**DCR's answer does solve the problem, but doesn't fix the core issue.**

If you simply convert the text to a number then you'll be trying the find the range of values between things like 3 and Q.

You're using the wrong input type in this case.

You need to use `<input type="number">`

```js
function calcRange() {
  let min = document.getElementById("min").value;
  let max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  let range = [];
  while (min <= max) {
    range.push(min++);
  }
  alert(range.join(','));
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="min" />
  <input type="number" id="max" />
  <button onclick="calcRange()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes sense, I'll switch that over too and keep it in mind going forward. Thank you!